# Name on interrail ticket

Tags: tickets, interrail

I booked interrail tickets for my group of friends through Myinterrail.com. However I mistakenly entered someone's name wrong. I thought he was an 'Alexander', whereas in reality he is just 'Alex'. All the other details such as passport numbers are correct.

I have contacted MyInterrail and their advice was to change the ticket. However this is a lengthy and expensive process.

Does anyone have any experience with this or know how thoroughly the passes are checked?

Is changing the name something that needs doing, or should we be able to get away with it?

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to have problems because the ticket says Alexander and the passport says Alex.

Comment: I've used interrail tickets a couple of times and don't think anyone checked my passport.

Comment: @Mark Perryman, I'll offer a competing anacdote that when I went it was checked a number of times.

Answer (score 2):

If the InterRail officials tell you that it is better to change the pass, it is better to change the pass.

Passports are often checked against the name on the pass in some countries and less often (to almost never) in others, and in several countries the train people will see Alex and Alexander as the same name, in other countries they may make a case out of it just because they can.
One fine and losing the pass (as it does not belong to this person, see the name is different) is likely more expensive than the name change.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this issue, I had the ticket changed (which cost around £60), but it would not have been an issue.

The tickets were checked on most trains, but not once against the passport, even for Eurostar.

In most cases, the ticket inspectors didn't really know what to do with interrail passes and just checked the dates.

Comment: As said in the comments on the question, some train guards do check against the passport and make a lot of fuss if there are differences.

Comment: I guess it may also have made a difference that I was travelling in a group of 8 on mostly busy trains and they mostly just wanted to check them as quickly as possible