# Entered short name instead of full name on eticket

Tags: tickets

I entered my brother's short name, Abhi, instead of Abhimanyu. Can he travel on this ticket or should I get the name corrected?

Comment: The authorities cannot correct this, it is the airline doing this. If you booked with an airline having a 24-hour free cancellation policy, the best way to proceed is to cancel the ticket. Otherwise, does your brother have another form of ID that actually carries the nickname and that is valid for travel on that trip? Finally, it is important where the ticket is going to: the USA are, for instance, very strict about the name exactly matching to the one on the passport. The safe course of action is to pay the change fee with the airline to get the name corrected.

Comment: what kind of ticket?

Comment: Preferably contact the airline ASAP. Even if they don't have a 24-hour free cancellation policy (many European airlines don't), they might have a 24-hour window for minor corrections. e.g. Ryanair allows "minor name changes" for free, or they might be willing to waive the fee.

Comment: I suppose you mean 'a ticket' and not 'an etiquette' (label, tag)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My last name is not the same on ticket as on passport; rest of details are same](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22088/my-last-name-is-not-the-same-on-ticket-as-on-passport-rest-of-details-are-same), and [Name on interrail ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116353/name-on-interrail-ticket), and [Name on RyanAir ticket abbreviated in passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38744/name-on-ryanair-ticket-abbreviated-in-passport)

Comment: @Giorgio I don't think there's any point closing this as a duplicate. We have no idea what kind of ticket the asker is talking about and they've not been back to the site in the two weeks since posting their question. We should just vote to close as unclear: this will never be answerable and any answer won't help the original asker.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I agree, a better approach, ty.